# What causes overhead in QEMU in case of trivial `sleep 1`?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm

#### Experiment:

I ran `sleep 1` under `strace -tt` (which reports timestamps of all syscalls) in host and QEMU guest, and noticed that the time required to reach a certain syscall (`clock_nanosleep`) is **almost twice larger in case of the guest:**

- **1.813 ms** on the host vs
- **3.396 ms** in the guest.

Here is [full host strace -tt sleep 1](https://gist.github.com/DimanNe/f1cc44b4c49ad970d80e35309225df5e) and here is [full QEMU strace -tt sleep 1](https://gist.github.com/DimanNe/2e965d00e784e82e76a13c5b3f978c26).

Below are excerpts where you can already see the difference:

Host:

```
Time    diff      timestamp (as reported by strace)
0.000 / 0.653 ms: 13:13:56.452820 execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "1"], 0x7ffded01ecb0 /* 53 vars */) = 0
0.653 / 0.023 ms: 13:13:56.453473 brk(NULL)               = 0x5617efdea000
0.676 / 0.063 ms: 13:13:56.453496 arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffeb7041b0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

QEMU:

```
Time    diff      timestamp (as reported by strace)
0.000 / 1.008 ms: 12:12:03.164063 execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "1"], 0x7ffd0bd93e50 /* 13 vars */) = 0
1.008 / 0.119 ms: 12:12:03.165071 brk(NULL)               = 0x55b78c484000
1.127 / 0.102 ms: 12:12:03.165190 arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffcb5dfd850) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

#### The questions:

- What causes the slowdown & overhead? It is not using any hardware (like GPU, disks, etc), so there is no translation layers. I also tried running the command several times to ensure everything that can be cached is cached in the guest.
- Is there a way to speed it up?

#### Update:

- With `cpupower frequency-set --governor performance` the timings are:

  - Host: 0.922ms
  - Guest: 1.412ms
- With image in `/dev/shm` (`-drive file=/dev/shm/root`):

  - Host: 0.922ms
  - Guest: 1.280ms

---

#### PS

I modified "bare" output of strace so that it include (1) time that starts from 0 with the first syscall followed by (2) duration of the syscall, for easier understanding. For completeness, the script is [here](https://gist.github.com/DimanNe/0e8683caf75340e13c733f08563388ba).

I started qemu in this way:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 4 -m 4G -nodefaults -no-user-config -nographic -no-reboot \
   -kernel $HOME/devel/vmlinuz-5.13.0-20-generic \
   -append 'earlyprintk=hvc0 console=hvc0 root=/dev/sda rw' \
   -drive file=$HOME/devel/images/root,if=ide,index=0,media=disk,format=raw \
   -device virtio-serial,id=virtio-serial0 -chardev stdio,mux=on,id=host-io,signal=off -device virtconsole,chardev=host-io,id=console0
```

Comment: Not sure if it can impact performance that much, but you are emulating a drive with QEMU, so all the filesystem operations done by OS/loader/program will take longer in the guest. You might want to try compiling your own simple C static executable that merely does a couple of syscalls and check the performance of that, which will give you a better idea of the peak performance you can achieve with KVM virtualization. Also, make sure to test with `performance` as scaling governor on the host and guest, so that timings are not affected by CPU freq scaling.

Comment: You may also want to try to run the same test but without a -drive and with -initrd instead, which lets the guest kernel simply load an initramfs image in RAM (you would first have to build an appropriate one though).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks, it improved timings (absolute as well as relative). I put entire guest filesystem in RAM (`/dev/shm`), as you suggested, but I would expect the guest to be even faster in this case (?)... Host OS does not have this "luxury"

Comment: I don't know if putting the raw image in `/dev/shm` does much, as it is still in the *host* (yes it's RAM, but still a host filesystem), so QEMU still has to do all the work for the guest. Instead, using `-initrd` will make the *guest* kernel load the filesystem in its RAM, theoretically without the need to do any VM exit from KVM to QEMU to service hardware requests like I suppose that `-drive` does. I'm not 100% sure though, this is only a supposition which is why I am commenting and not posting an answer.

Comment: When I ran `time strace -tt sleep 1`, I got `real 0m1.017s`. Do you know why you get `1813 ms` on your host ?

Comment: Sure, *total* time should be 1s. However in the post I measure time to `clock_nanosleep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my (custom-built kernel) was missing `CONFIG_HYPERVISOR_GUEST=y` option (and a couple of nested options).

Answer (score 0):

That's expected, considering the way `strace` is implemented, i.e. via the `ptrace(2)` system call: every time the traced process performs a system call or gets a signal, the process is forcefully *stopped* and the control is passed to the tracing process, which in the case of `strace` does all the unpacking & printing *synchronously*, i.e. while keeping the traced process stopped.  That's the kind of path which increases any emulation overhead exponentially.

It would be instructive to strace `strace` itself -- you will see that does not let the traced process continue (with `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, ...)`) until it has processed & written out everything related to the current system call.

Notice that in order to run a "trivial" `sleep 1` command, the dynamic linker will perform a couple dozen system calls before even getting to the entry point of the `sleep` binary.

I don't think that optimizing `strace` is worth spending time on; if you were planning to run strace as an auditing instead of a debugging tool (by running production tasks under `strace` or similar), you should reconsider your designs ;-)

Comment: This doesn't explain much if anything. Of course a `strace`'d process is going to run slower than its non-traced counterpart, but that should happen on both the native host and in the KVM VM... what slows things down is the virtualization overhead.

Comment: Well I'm sorry if you don't get it, I'm not here to preach you. Yes, *intutively*, the slowdown should be probably assumed to grow linearly when running under kvm, but intuition fails. I'm not going to write an asynchronous `strace` just to demonstrate my point ;-)

Comment: @user17343903 Just a clarification regarding "don't think that optimizing strace is worth spending time on". It all started with Chrome. On my host it scores 213.989 in JetStream benchmark, while in the guest it scores 94.570. So I decided to start with something much simpler than Chrome...

Comment: All I'm saying is that your answer seems to be merely suggesting that the culprit of the "problem" is `strace`, when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Running qemu on my mac, I found 'sleep 1' at the *bash* command line usually taking 10 seconds while 'sleep 2' usually taking 5 seconds. At least as measured by *time* on a 6.0.8 archlinux. Oddly *time* seemed to be measuring the passage of time correctly while *sleep* was not working.

But I had been running

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 1G \
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 \
    img1.cow
```

Then reading about the -icount parameter, I found the following makes the sleep pretty accurate.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -icount shift=auto,sleep=on \
    -m 1G \
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 \
    img1.cow
```

I mention it here because my search for *qemu* and *slow* *sleep 1* led me here first.